# Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ca

I have this network structure and I should do the creation, when I launch the create_network.sh script, I get the following error message:

[error + create-network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ftv5.png)

[tree-network pt.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTDFA.png)

[tree-network pt.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsd57.png)

[tree-network pt.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRK16.png)

[docker-compose.yaml (peer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMH18.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose.yaml, the volume mounts for the MSP and TLS folders appear to be incorrect.  The compose file is mounting "../certs/msp" (and tls) into the peer container, which is reading the certificates from /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp.  In your directory listing above, the org2 assets do not contain the msp and tls certificates, which is likely causing the error above.

Double-check that the output of the `cryptogen` and/or CA output path aligns with the volume mount in your docker compose file.  See the sample at fabric-samples/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml for an example of how tls/msp certificates can be linked up with the output of a cryptogen command.

Also I noticed from your compose descriptor that you are running a slightly out of date revision of fabric (2.2).  Please consider upgrading to the new gateway client application release 2.4.1, as the programming model for both chaincode and client / application development has been greatly simplified.  In addition, please check out the new test-network for Kubernetes (fabric-samples/test-network-k8s) as it provides a more detailed explanation and realistic usage of CAs when setting up a Fabric network.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply;
Unfortunately I get the network structure from a wizard made previously not by me, I tried to update the version, the cryptogen / CA output file. But the error persists.
Also the error does not give it to me alone on org2.